# The Configuration File is not initializing

Tags: c#, winforms

When i run my application i get this message:

> An unhandled exception of type
>
> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException occurred in
>
> GridEmulator.exe Additional information: Configuration system failed to initialize

This is my App.Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="VM1" value="192.168.1.2" />
    <add key="VM2" value="MyPC" />
  </appSettings>
   <TestConfig>
    <DinoConfig Alpha="" Beta="" Gamma="" Delta="">
      <Dino Zelta="" Platform="" Rho="" iota="" />
     </DinoConfig>
  </TestConfig>
</configuration>
```

And this is the part of C# code which is causing problem:

```
private string[] vmStrings;
 vmStrings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys
               .Where(key => key.StartsWith("VM"))
               .Select(key => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key])
               .ToArray();
```

Can anybody please help?

Comment: You have a section named TestConfig not defined anywhere in your config file. If you remove it does it start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test Config definition was missing from the above mentioned xml. Defining that solved the problem. Thanks Steve.